# I'm having trouble using SCP to upload files to Sourceforge

Tags: shell, scp, sourceforge, winscp

So I finished writing my first program and I'm trying to upload it to my sourceforge account, but the file size is to big to use the normal html5 upload manager sourceforge provides. Soursceforge says "For larger files, use FTP, SCP, or rsync". They also provided [this page for references of what to commands to send via the command line](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Release%20files%20for%20download#AccessingReleasesviaShell) like this one, which I had no idea how to use

```
scp file.zip jsmith@frs.sourceforge.net:/home/frs/project/fooproject/Rel_1
```

Should I be able to run this through the WinSCP.com prompt like so?

```
WinSCP> scp file.zip jsmith@frs.sourceforge.net:/home/frs/project/fooproject/Rel_1
```

Seeing as how the commandline kicked my but (I'm totally open to learning how to use the commandline for file transfer to sourceforge if you have any links to any tutorials, [this one was too difficult to understand with all the broken English](http://www.scriptol.com/how-to/upload-web-pages-to-sourceforge.php) :/ ), I tried creating a connection with the WinSCP GUI and the following info

**Host:** myusername@frs.sourceforge.net

**Username:** MyUsername

**Password:** MyPassword

but I get the following error before the SCP connection is finished

> Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exist
> status 1.
>
> Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible
> with the application (bash is recommended).

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. From what I've gathered I should learn  more about shells, but I have no idea where to begin. Thanks in advance and cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You are using SCP protocol with WinSCP. Make sure you use SFTP.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're trying to do something weird with WinSCP. You're trying the "Open Terminal" option, which, I think just tries to open an ssh session at the host. But, we don't support ssh sessions to the frs.sourceforge.net

Normally, if you try to ssh to that host, you get this message:

Welcome!

This is a restricted Shell Account.
You can only copy files to/from here.

Connection to frs.sourceforge.net closed.

But I think WinSCP eats that, or something.
Anyway, I think what you need to do is just use WinSCP as a graphical two-pane sftp client. Navigate to the file to upload on the left, and to the destination directory on the right, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the best place to ask this kind of question is one of the three following:

The sourceforge channel on irc.freenode.net

Email support at sfnet_ops@geek.net

Open a ticket at https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/new/

While we do sort of monitor Stackoverflow, it's not our fastest support channel. I've asked one of our support engineers to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to connect:

1. select protocol SCP
2. Click Advanced
3. Environment --> SCP/Shell --> Shell (see 3 in red): change the shell that is available on the target server

It can connect to Windows 10's ssh server, with git bash

[image]

Comment: But why? Why don't you stick with the default SFTP?